# Add different navbar on different pages with layout.js next js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

[image]I've two navbar layout and ten pages in my next js project. Now I need to set navbar one for five pages and navbar two for rest of the pages with layout.js at once. How can I do this. If anyone help me about this, I'll be very thankful. Thanks in advance.

NavbarOne.js

```
const NavbarOne = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Navbar One</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NavbarOne;
```

NavbarTwo.js

```
const NavbarTwo = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Navbar Two</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NavbarTwo;
```

Layout.js

```
import Footer from "../Footer";
import NavbarOne from "../Navbar/NavbarOne";


const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <NavbarOne />
            {/* <NavbarTwo /> */}
            {children}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

_app.js

```
import Layout from '../components/layout/Layout';
import '../styles/styles.scss'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default MyApp
```

Updated

Layout.js

```
import Footer from "../Footer";
import NavbarOne from "../Navbar/NavbarOne";
import NavbarTwo from "../Navbar/NavbarTwo";


const Layout = ({ children, criteria}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            { criteria ?
              <NavbarOne />
              :
              <NavbarTwo />
            }
            {children}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

__app.js

```
import Layout from '../components/layout/Layout';
import '../styles/styles.scss'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout criteria={true}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default MyApp
```

__admission.js

```
import Layout from "../components/layout/Layout";

const admission = () => {
    return (
        <Layout criteria={false}>
            <div>
            <h1>Admission</h1>
        </div>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default admission;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like

```
const Layout = ({ children, criteria }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            { criteria ? //ternary operator
              <NavbarOne />
              :
              <NavbarTwo />
            }
            {children}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

And pass a boolean to your Layout as criteria to choose between Navbars

```
const Page1 = () => {
    return (
        <Layout criteria={true}> // will display navbar 1
          <p>Im page 1</p>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

```
const Page2 = () => {
    return (
        <Layout criteria={false}> // will display navbar 2
          <p>Im page 2</p>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

---

With three navbars you can do

```
const Layout = ({ children, navbarType }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            { navbarType == 1 &&  <NavbarOne />}
            { navbarType == 2 &&  <NavbarTwo />}
            { navbarType == 3 &&  <NavbarThree />}
            {children}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

And pass a number to your Layout as navbarType to choose between Navbars

```
const Page1 = () => {
    return (
        <Layout navbarType={1}> // will display navbar 1
          <p>Im page 1</p>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

```
const Page2 = () => {
    return (
        <Layout navbarType={2}> // will display navbar 2
          <p>Im page 2</p>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

```
const Page3 = () => {
    return (
        <Layout navbarType={3}> // will display navbar 3
          <p>Im page 3</p>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I didn't get it.

Comment: Do you want me to explain or to wish you luck ?

Comment: It'll be great for me. If you explain. Thank you

Comment: I did edit my answer with details

Comment: You can accept this answer if it suits your requirements =)

Comment: I'm facing another problem. I updated the question. Please take a look.  I pass criteria=true default to all pages. And for one page I pass criteria=false. But it doesn't work. It calls all of the  components double time that I added to Layout.js. Please take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246511/discussion-between-mahabub-hossain-and-jeanjacquesgourdin).

Comment: You are putting twice the Layout component, so it is a normal behaviour. You wrap it it _app and _admission...

Comment: In that case what can I do?

Comment: The easiest way is to wrap only in your pages so that you have full control on every page

Comment: yeah, I got it and it works. Thank you for your time and patience. Have a good day!

Comment: Hello, Can you please help me little bit, If I have  three or four navbar, on that situation how this function will be look like. Thank you

Comment: Done, you can check answer

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer an option where, you want to add N number of navbars.
and select them by some index number.

```
import Footer from "../Footer";
import NavbarOne from "../Navbar/NavbarOne";


const Layout = ({ children, index }) => {
    const navBarList = [<NavbarOne />, <NavbarTwo />];
    const renderNavBar = (_index) => navBarList[_index];

    return (
        <div>
            {renderNavBar(index)}
            {children}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

**In your where you calling your app, you should be calling it as such.**

```
import Layout from './components/layout.js';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Layout index={1}>
        <p>byebye</p>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I didn't get it. I updated the question. While I'm calling Layout.js in _app.js, It renders navbarOne. But some of my pages need NavbarTwo. On that situation how can i remove navbarOne for specific page and add navbarTwo.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `props` called `navbar` to the Layout Component like this:

```
export default function PageOne() {
    return (
        <Layout navbar="one">
            <div className="container">
                <h1>Page One</h1>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default function PageTwo() {
    return (
        <Layout navbar="two">
            <div className="container">
                <h1>Page Two</h1>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

And later render the Navbar Components conditionally like this:

```
const Layout = ({ children, navbar }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            { navbar === 'one' && <NavbarOne />}
            { navbar === 'two' && <NavbarTwo />}
            {children}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I didn't get it. I updated the question. While I'm calling Layout.js in _app.js, It renders navbarOne. But some of my pages need NavbarTwo. On that situation how can i remove navbarOne for specific page and add navbarTwo.

Comment: @MahabubHossain
Instead of calling the Layout in _app.js you should call it in every page component with the extra props I mentioned. That way it will work.